# Can we have angular js with spring 3.x framework I want to use Spring JDBC for DAO operation and angularjs for UI

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

Can we have angular js with spring 3.x framework. I want to use Spring JDBC for DAO operation, HTML, angularjs(mainly for GRID) following Spring MVC pattern. Please suggest link for sample application, if any.

Comment: Of course you can use both. You should use the latest version instead of the old, obsolete 3.x branch though. But asking for links is off-topic. Voting to close.

Comment: Thanks Nizet. We can have as well Spring-Security DAO authentication and authorization with spring security userDetailsService implementation. Ohhh! that was off-topic.

Comment: What do you mean by GRID?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any JS library on the front end as far as I am aware.